# Python: for loop up to the shorter of two lists

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to do a for loop with two lists that takes the shorter of the two and only goes up to that:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b']

for val in (list1 up to length of list2)
    print val
```

output should be:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Do you first need to determine which of the lists is shorter or is that already known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip()`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b']
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
  print(a)
#1
#2
```

If you want to do it manually, use this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b']
m = min(len(list1), len(list2)) # get the minimum length
for i in range(m):
  print(list1[i])
#1
#2
```

However, I would recommend `zip()`, since it does everything for you. It's just good to be able to do something without having to depend on special programming language features.